# How to say "except all of those rules" in flex?

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, flex-lexer

I defined some regular expressions and rules in flex. Now i want to write a regular expression that does the following: if there is an input that does not match any of rules i defined, i want to just simply print out that input. You may think that since it is not matched with any of the rules, it will automatically be printed out, but that is not the case. Consider my example, i defined the following regular expressions:

```
[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*    printf("%d tIDENT (%s)\n",lineNum,yytext);
```

This rule defines an identifier, an identifier can start with underscore or with a letter, and it is a combination of letters, numbers and underscore.

```
[0-9]+  printf("%d tPOSINT (%s)\n",lineNum,yytext,yytext);
```

This rule recognizes the positive integers.

Assume these are my only rules, and the input is `2a3`. This is not an identifier, and not an integer. But my output takes `2` as integer, and then takes `a3` as identifier. But `2a3` does not match with any of the rules, i want to print it out as it is. How can i do this?

Comment: For example you can add some separators(blank space, etc) and match the tokens along with those separators.

Comment: I don't believe you can do that easily. I'm not even sure you're thinking about this the right way - with these definitions that you have the two tokens 2 and a3 should indeed be the output for the input 2a3. What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: The way you've defined it, it will recognize a number when you feed it "2a3".  Are you trying to reject any *sequence* of IDs and numbers?

Comment: The way i defined it, it first recognizes 2 as integer, and a3 as identifier. @500 - Internal Server Error i think if the input is 2 a3 then it is ok, but i think if it is 2a3, we need to consider the whole string as one, and try to look if it matches a rule. Am i mistaken?

Comment: That depends on your grammar definition. I'm not intimately familiar with flex but in some scanner generators you can have a more greedy definition appear before a less greedy one and have the token be recognized by the first rule that matches any of the input and not try any other ones.

Comment: What I mean by "depends on your grammar" is, whether `2a3` is a valid token or not is determined by your grammar, but from your definition of IDENT above it sounds like it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You may think that since it is not matched with any of the rules, it will automatically be printed out

No, I don't think that. If I remember correctly, it prints an error saying something like 'flex jammed' if the input doesn't match any rules. But in this case the input does match your rules, so it doesn't happen. If it isn't supposed to match, change your rules accordingly. But I would leave it. 2 followed by a3 won't be legal syntax anyway, so let the parser deal with it.

To avoid the jam message and print out the non-match, you need to add a final rule like this:

.  { printf("%s", yytext); }. // or whatever you want

You also need to add a white space rule.